# How can I control imageView's moving by PanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to move imageView by PanGestureRecognizer like this
(imageView can be scaled)

1. If imageView's position is (0,0), it can't move.
2. If imageView's position x is over 60, it can't move more.
3. If imageView's position y is over 80, it can't move more.
4. When imageView's scale is restored(1.0), it's position is (0,0).

It is difficult to restrict imageView's moving and position.
What should I do?

Here is my code.

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a.jpg"]];
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 448);
imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view imgView];


- (void)panAction : (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint CGP = imgView.center;

    if(newScale != 1.0 && CGP.x-160 != 0 && CGP.y-224 != 50){

    CGPoint p = [sender translationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint movedPoint = CGPointMake(imgView.center.x + p.x, imgView.center.y + p.y);
    imgView.center = movedPoint;


    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
}


-(void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
    }

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

        // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
        const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.0;
        const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

        newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
        newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the following condition check in your Pan Gesture action:
   For you information, as you move the object, this panAction() method is called regularly at each pixel move.

```
- (void)panAction : (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
  //Do something whatever you need to be done while the pan gesture starts 
}
if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
  //Do something whatever you need to be done while the imageView object is in the moving state  
}
if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
 //Do something you need to do as you end the pan gesture.
}
}
```